# Is there property to search in a value list in janus gridex by Containes text

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-forms-designer, gridex

I am bindind a combo in janus gridex with value list. combo binding successfully. But i face a problem when i am searching from this combo. it always search with BeginWith value. I want to apply search that search with containes. My Code is

grdFreight.RootTable.Columns["Transporter"].ColumnType = Janus.Windows.GridEX.ColumnType.Text;
grdFreight.RootTable.Columns["Transporter"].HasValueList = true;
grdFreight.RootTable.Columns["Transporter"].LimitToList = true;
grdFreight.RootTable.Columns["Transporter"].EditType = Janus.Windows.GridEX.EditType.Combo;
grdFreight.RootTable.Columns["Transporter"].Caption = "Transporter";                grdFreight.RootTable.Columns["Transporter"].ValueList.PopulateValueList(dtAccountlst.DefaultView, "Id", "AccountTitle");
grdFreight.RootTable.Columns["Transporter"].Width = 120;

i want to apply search on value list that search with containes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "search" into a UIComboBox control.
The ComboBox select behavior is TypeAhead, so it works using a begins with way.

Even if you try to filter the combobox datasource you will have troubles in displaying other row values, since it's displaymember is user in any FormattingRow event and if the filter removes rows in your dataview, you'll get the value instead of text.

I think you can't do it in the way you want.
:(